# Are the Rényi entropies mutually orthogonal over density matrices

Tags: quantum-information, entropy, density-operator

For a density matrix $\rho \in D(\mathcal{H})$, the quantum Rényi entropy is defined as
$$S_α(\rho) = \frac{1}{1-\alpha} \log \mathrm{tr}(\rho^\alpha), \alpha \in (0,1)\cup(1,∞)$$

Does it satisfy the orthogonality condition
$$\int S_α^*(\rho) S_\beta(\rho)d\rho = \delta_{\alpha \beta} $$
?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Renyi entropies are non-negative numbers.

Moreover, they are all non-zero on all non-pure states.

So no, they won't satisfy such an orthogonality relation.

(Note that it is not even clear what your integral $\mathrm{d}\rho$ means - but this won't affect the answer, unless you integrate over pure states.)